# WPF: Rotate a rectangle with slider

Tags: c#, wpf, rotation, slider, rectangles

I'm trying to rotate a rectangle when scrolling slider
there are 2 steps: Click on a rectangle - Scroll the slider.
If I draw only one rectangle, everything is ok.
But when I draw 2 rectangles or more and start rotating, all of my rectangle are rotated together with same angle.
I have no idea about this.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance!
Here is my code: (I found the code for rotating at another post in this page)

```
    Shape _shape;
    RotateTransform rt = new RotateTransform();
        private void MyCanvas_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs)
        {

                        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                        //for know which rectangle has been clicked
                        if (MyTransform_type == TRANSFORM_TYPE.ROTATE)
                        {
                            _shape = e.OriginalSource as Shape;
                            if (_shape != null)
                            {
                               _shape = (Shape)e.OriginalSource;
                            }
                        }

                }


        private void MyCanvas_MouseRightButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
                {
                    if (MyTransform_type != TRANSFORM_TYPE.NONE && MyTransform_type != TRANSFORM_TYPE.ROTATE)
                    {
                        if (_shape == null)
                            return;
                        //_shape.ReleaseMouseCapture();
                        Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
                    }
                }



        private void sldRotate_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
                {
                    if (_shape != null)
                    { 
                        _shape.RenderTransform = rt;
                        _shape.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
                        var da = new DoubleAnimation(rt.Angle, sldRotate.Value, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.001)));
                        rt.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, da);
                        rt.Angle = sldRotate.Value;
                    }


  }
```

Comment: please add the complete code, e.g. where do you set "rt"?

Comment: "rt" is on the top of my code :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is that you create a single RotateTransform object and assign it to the different shapes. So after clicking on several rectangles, every rectangle has the same rotatetransform instance. If you now change the value of the rotatetransform, every rectangle will rotate...

In order to fix that you should change your sldRotate_ValueChanged method. Check if the current shape has already a rotatetransform. If not then create one, if yes adjust the rotatetransform...

Additionally, if you have such a small animation time, you can just leave it out:

```
private void sldRotate_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    if (_shape != null)
    {
        var rt = new RotateTransform();
        rt.Angle = sldRotate.Value;
        _shape.RenderTransform = rt;
        _shape.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the same RotateTransform named "rt" for all of your rectangles. The simpliest solution will be:

```
    private void MyCanvas_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs)
    {                        
        if (MyTransform_type == TRANSFORM_TYPE.ROTATE)
        {
           _shape = e.OriginalSource as Shape;

           //creating new RotateTransform
           rt=new RotateTransform();

           if (_shape != null)
           {
              _shape = (Shape)e.OriginalSource;
           }
        }
    }
```

also you could do

```
    _shape.RenderTransform = rt;
```

in MyCanvas_MouseRightButtonDown after

```
    _shape = e.OriginalSource as Shape;
```

instead of doing it each time, when sldRotate_ValueChanged executes to avoid unneeded assignments.